# Execute inline javascript in another file

Tags: javascript

In my site I have inline javascript.

I have this in my header:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function eml(person, domain) {
            document.write('<'+'a h'+'ref="ma'+'ilto'+':'+person+'@'+domain+'">'+person+'@'+domain+'</a>');
</script>
```

And this in the body:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    eml('info','site.com');</script>
<noscript><span class="eml">deni.elpar@com</span></noscript>
```

So I need to make this javascript not inline and execute it from a js file. However, this function, as it is at the moment, does not work if executed from a different file, so I need suggestions on how to rewrite it. Thanks!

Comment: `So I need to take out this js code but I do not know how to do that.` - edit the file with your choice of editor ... remove the unwanted code ... profit

Comment: :) think I did not try? I tried ... and I prayed .... Still no answer :D

Answer (score 4):

You would copy just the js to another file, let's say newfile.js, for example.

Then in your html page add the tag:

```
<script src="newfile.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // execute function after resources are loaded
    window.onload = function() {
        eml('info','site.com'); 
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Exactly this is my idea, but it will not work if it the code is the same

Comment: I think the problem you're having is that you're executing elm before the other script has loaded, you need a method to delay the execution of your call until the other file is loaded.

Comment: Yes! Exactly! So I decided to put all my inline js in a separate file which is loaded after the scripts I need, but then I need to modify the initial inline javascript which is not my filed and I really need help

Comment: The reason why the other scripts are executed not on time is that my SEO insists on making them load asynchronously. So this is a problem

Answer (score -1):

I will suggest you take that header part and write all code in the same script tag in a body section.

function eml(person, domain) {
        document.write(''+person+'@'+domain+'');
    eml('info','site.com');


deni.elpar@com

Comment: If I understand you right, this is how it is done at the moment. But I need to rewrite this so it works from another file like @databyss suggested

Comment: If you want to access from another file. 
1- Then create a new js file.
2- Write your function in the new file.
3- Attach that js file in the file you are working.
4- Now call the function declared in the new js file in the file you are working.

Hope it make sense.

Comment: Do you think if I write this code the same as here it will execute? Because this is the problem - it does not and this is understandable.

Comment: If I could do all of that I would not write the question for sure ;)